# Getting "Syntax Error: Unexpected Token" when calling a function from ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm getting Syntax Errors when calling a php file with ajax.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token F
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token F
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token F
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token F
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token F
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token F
```

The `change_produkt` function is called with an onclick event in a checkbox field.
The output of this function is as following:

[image: Return of change_produkt function]

Now, I call the second function `fill_optionen` and pass the arrays to that function. It's doing ajax calls for each object. (6 times in this case)

Javascript:

```
function fill_optionen(optionen) {
     console.log("fill_optionen called.."); // Debug
     var text = "";

     $j.each(JSON.parse(optionen), function (index, value) {

        jQuery.ajax({
           url: 'include/mutation_helper.php',
           data: {func: "render_opt", option: value},
           type: 'post',
           success: function(output) {
              console.log(JSON.parse(output)); // Debug

           }
        });
     });
  }

function change_produkt() {
     console.log("change_produkt called.."); // Debug

     var id_produkt = $j("#produkt").val();
     console.log("DEBUG -- id_produkt:"+id_produkt);

     jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'include/mutation_helper.php',
        data: {func: "get_opts", produkt: id_produkt},
        type: 'post',
        success: function(output) {
           console.log(JSON.parse(output)); // Debug

           fill_optionen(output);
        }
     });
  }
```

PHP:

```
function render_opt() {
    if(!isset($_POST['option'])) {
      echo json_encode("error");
      exit;
    }

    $opt = $_POST['option'];

    $render = render($opt, $_SESSION['mutation']);

    echo json_encode("hello");
}
```

As soon as I remove the line which calls the `render` function, it works. But why is there an error? I'm not even printing out that `$render` variable.
(The `render` function only returns html code in a string.)

Comment: As a side note, instead of calling multiple ajax requests in a loop, you'd have better to call only once with all values to pass and set logic server side

Comment: according to your code, this line `$render = render($option, $_SESSION['mutation']);` should be `$render = render($opt, $_SESSION['mutation']);` ?

Comment: @SearchAndResQ You're right. But the errors are still there.

Comment: @A.Wolff Thank's for the tip. I will change it later.

Comment: If the error disappears as soon as you remove the `render` function call, but that function itself produces no output – then perhaps it/calling it is generating an error message/warning instead? Look at the actual response your AJAX call is getting in the network panel of your browser’s developer tools – what does that look like?

Comment: @CBroe That was my guess too. I executed the render_option function in a temporarely php file. I enabled the error reporting. There are a few warning messages. Do I need to fix them first?

Comment: Of course you do, otherwise those messages are part of the response your AJAX request gets, and invalidate the JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have an PHP error inside your `render` function. And then PHP prints out its error, which later causes the JavaScript error. Because JSON is excepted as returned output by the ajax request and you got a string back containing the PHP error message. Please look at your browser debugger under the ajax request raw network data, what is really returned.

Comment: The render_option function called another function, which was not present. I did not know that there is a special response tab in the developer tools. Something else that I've learned :) Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery will automatically detect a JSON response and deserialise it for you. Calling `JSON.parse` on the resulting object will cause errors - as you've seen. Try this:

```
success: function(output) {
    console.log(output); // Debug
    fill_optionen(output);
}
```

Comment: But the errors are not caused by the `console.log` action. I tried it but the errors are still there. :(